# Why do graduate programs have comprehensive examinations (comps)?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, exams

I'm about to begin studying for the comprehensive examinations (comps) my masters program (Computer Information Systems) requires.  I'm curious as to the point of even having them in the first place.  I'm not concerned about whether or not I'll pass my comps.  I know that I will.  It just seems like a lot of wasted time in both preparation and the fact that I'll have to burn a precious day of vacation to take them.

I could understand if, as stated in another post regarding PhD programs, we were required to take them after our first year of the program as part of a larger weeding out process.  However, that isn't the case.  We're simply required to take them before graduation.

In four separate exams, we're tested on the four core courses for our program.  Didn't I pass those courses already?  Haven't I already earned a satisfactory/passing grade for each course?

Would someone please provide my ignornant mind with some insight into the possible reasons why?  It feels like double jeopardy...  Thanks!

EDIT:
The exams are written by the same instructors who taugh the specific class I took.  For example, both Dr. Jones and Dr. Smith teach CourseX.  However, since I took Dr. Jones for that course, he is the person who wrote the comp for the course.  At least, that's my understanding of how they're written and by whom.  I apologize for leaving this nugget out.  I shouldn't write these questions while I'm sleep deprived...

Comment: In mathematics, such things are intended to make people look at things again, for reinforcement, and to possibly reconsider them from a slightly more mature viewpoint. Rehearsals.

Comment: "Didn't I pass those courses already?" - Yes, but not all instructors of graduate courses hold the same bar to their students.  A common exam can serve to ensure the quality of the student independently of who taught it, or when/how it was taught.  As you may already know, teaching isn't much of a priority to professors as research is, so just because you passed the class doesn't necessarily mean you've learned enough to delve into the uncertainties of cutting-edge, original research.

Comment: @Paul Don't know if that is a duplicate. The prelim/qualifiers and the comprehensive are different in some some places. My graduate program had both. One to show that you were ready for graduate coursework and the other to show what you had learned from your graduate coursework.

Comment: "I'll have to burn a precious day of vacation to take them". That seems like a pretty legit reason to abandon comps. Voted to close.

Comment: Meh. All the answers to the alleged duplicate address exams that cover undergrad material early in a grad-students tenure, but the question is explicitly about exams that test graduate material later in the students residence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about exams taken at the *end* of a master's program. I have given such exams. In my mind, they make the candidate *prove* that they have mastered the material of the courses, which is a form of quality control. But the exams also have a few secondary goals in my mind:

- By studying for the exams, students gain more understanding of the material, and come away better educated. The actual *taking* of the exam is less important, in a sense, than the time spent studying. If a student studies well, they should pass the exam.
- The exams keep the faculty honest when teaching, because the faculty know their students will have to pass exams that will be seen by other faculty. Exams within a course are often not seen by other faculty, so the instructor is not as publicly accountable.
- The exams help the faculty see what the students know, all in one setting. We can use this to revise courses at the departmental level if we find that many students have the same gaps in their knowledge.

Comment: It was your second and third bullets that provided me with the answers I hadn't considered.  Thanks!